# Backbone.js model.isValid() method not returning false for an invalid model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

so I am trying to get the validate from my model to actually disable the save button but to re-validate when new input is included. Anyone know the best way to attempt this. Thanks! The problem I have with my method is that once it is disabled it doesn't return in state.

Here is the main.js file

```
(function () {
    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
        Templates: {},
        Router: {}

    };

    // MODEL
    App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            firstName: 'first',
            lastName: 'last',
            email: 'Email',
            phone: '222',
            birthday: '07/22/1980'
       },

        validate: function (attrs) {

            if (!attrs.firstName) {
                return 'You must enter a real first name.';
            }
            if (!attrs.lastName) {
                return 'You must enter a real last name.';
            }
            if (attrs.email.length < 5) {
                return 'You must enter a real email.';
            }
            if (attrs.phone.toString().length < 10 ) {
                //&& attrs.phone === int
               return 'You must enter a real phone number, if you did please remove the dash and spaces.';
            }
           // if (attrs.birthday.length < 2) {
             //   return 'You must enter a real city.';
            //}
        },

        initialize: function() {
             this.on('invalid', function (model, invalid) {
                console.log(invalid);
                alert(invalid);
            });
        }

    });

    //var userModel = new App.Models.User();

    //VIEW
    App.Views.User = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#user',
        //model: userModel,
        //tagName: 'div',
        //id: 'user',
        //className: 'userProfile',
        //template: _.template($("#userTemplate").html()),
        //editTemplate: _.template($("#userEditTemplate").html()),


        initialize: function (){

        },

        render: function() {
            this.template = Handlebars.compile($("#userTemplate").html());
            this.editTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#userEditTemplate").html());

            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        },

        events: {
            'click button.edit': 'editProfile',
            'click input.save': 'saveEdits',
            'click button.cancel': 'cancelEdits'
        },

        editProfile: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.editTemplate(this.model.toJSON()));

        }, 

        saveEdits: function () {
            var form = $(this.el).find('form#updateUser');
            this.model.set({

                firstName : form.find('.firstName').val(),
                lastName : form.find('.lastName').val(),
                email: form.find('.email').val(),
                phone: form.find('.phone').val(),
                birthday: form.find('.birthday').val()

            }, {validate: true} );

        if(!this.model.isValid()) {
            console.log('run');
            $('.save').attr("disabled", "disabled");

        } else {
            console.log('run2');
            alert('Changes have been made.');
            $('.save').removeAttr("disabled");
            return this.render();
        }


    },


        },

        cancelEdits: function() {
            this.render();
        }

    });
    //start history service
    Backbone.history.start();

    var user = new App.Views.User({model: new App.Models.User()});
    user.render();
})();
```

And here is the Jade File:

```
extends layout
block content   
    div.centerContent

        h4 User goes here with equal before it no space
            div#user
                p #{firstName} #{lastName}
                p #{email}
                p #{phone}
                p #{birthday}
                button.edit Edit

        script(id="userTemplate", type ="text/template")
                p {{firstName}} {{lastName}} 1
                p {{email}} 2 
                p {{phone}} 3 
                p {{birthday}} 4
                button.edit Edit

        script(id="userEditTemplate", type ="text/template")
            div
                form(action="#")#updateUser
                    input(type="text", class="firstName", value='{{firstName}}') 
                    input(type="text", class="lastName", value='{{lastName}}')
                    input(type="email", class="email", value='{{email}}')
                    input(type="number", class="phone",, value='{{phone}}')
                    input(type="date", class="birthday", value='{{birthday}}')
                input(type="submit", value="Save").save Save
                button.cancel Cancel
        hr
        script(type="text/javascript", src="/js/main.js")
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that you're calling the `{ validate: true }` option to your `model.set` method, then you're subsequently calling `model.isValid()`.

When you call `model.set` with the `validate` option set to true, Backbone.js will not set the properties you pass unless they all pass validation. So, by the time you call `model.isValid()` the model has been changed back to the previous version (before the `.set` call). `model.isValid()` automatically calls the `model.validate()` method and passes the current attributes of the model to it.

In your example, the values being passed to `validate` by the `isValid` method are the current (*valid*) attributes of your model. Because of this, `isValid()` is always going to validate to true. Which will cause you to never reach your `else` clause.

The solution here is instead of calling `isValid` to see if your model is valid (after passing `validate: true` to the `set` method) check the value of `model.validationError`. If `model.validationError` is a truthy value, then you know your model is invalid.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aM7db/4/) with an example of how to do that, with some documentation.

Comment: I did what you said but now, it does not disable after I do input the correct text

Comment: @Lion789: What do you have, other than the unreachable `saveEdits` method, that would `$('.save').removeAttr('disabled')`?

Comment: I am not sure what that means?